# 2 monitors Ubuntu 18.04.4 (HDMI > HDMI & VGA > USB C)

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, asus, xrandr, usb-c

### **Update!!**

Ok so I figured that I can only get the screens mirrored with the adapter which didn't solve my problem. So instead I got VGA to USB C cable so each screen connected to it's own port but for some reason the USB C port is not detected. I have tested the cable on my Mac and it works fine, just not on Ubuntu. So clearly this is driver issue. Does anyone have experience with this on Asus UX433FA laptops? Here is my lsusb output:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:56cb IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

---

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.4 on my Asus UX433FA-A5155T. I just bought myself a 2nd monitor and trying to set it up, not as easy as I thought. Here is my set up.

I have one HDMI port connected with HDMI splitter to the 2 monitors. If I plugin the splitter the 2 monitors displays for brief moment in mirrored mode and then it just returns back to my laptop display and both external monitors just black screen. I suspect this can be something to do with the refresh rate but can't be certain.

I played around with xrandr to get the monitors to display which I got one stage in mirrored mode but obviously this is not want I want to achieve, I would like them to flow into each other, each monitor on its own.

I have gathered some information to display what I have, hope this works. If someone can just please let me know if they got their 3 monitors working with Ubuntu 18.04.

**Graphics Card:**

description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz

**Xrandr results:**

Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1920x1080     60.05 +  60.01    59.97*   59.96    59.93
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88
   1600x1024     60.17
   1400x1050     59.98
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82
   1280x1024     60.02
   1440x900      59.89
   1400x900      59.96    59.88
   1280x960      60.00
   1440x810      60.00    59.97
   1368x768      59.88    59.85
   1360x768      59.80    59.96
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91
   1152x864      60.00
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74
   1024x768      60.04    60.00
   960x720       60.00
   928x696       60.05
   896x672       60.01
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82
   960x600       59.93    60.00
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25
   840x525       60.01    59.88
   864x486       59.92    59.57
   800x512       60.17
   700x525       59.98
   800x450       59.95    59.82
   640x512       60.02
   720x450       59.89
   700x450       59.96    59.88
   640x480       60.00    59.94
   720x405       59.51    58.99
   684x384       59.88    59.85
   680x384       59.80    59.96
   640x400       59.88    59.98
   576x432       60.06
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32
   512x384       60.00
   512x288       60.00    59.92
   480x270       59.63    59.82
   400x300       60.32    56.34
   432x243       59.92    59.57
   320x240       60.05
   360x202       59.51    59.13
   320x180       59.84    59.32
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got feedback from ASUS. Turns out the USB-C port can only be used for data transfer and not display thus only one display port on this laptop model and that is the HDMI port.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling with the same issue, physically inspect your USBC port on the laptop.
If has a ⚡ (lightning bolt) printed next to the port than it supports Video output.
If it doesn't have anything printed next to the port, than it doesn't supports Video output.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1228547)